# SKNW package error

Tags: python, 3d

I'm using the SKNW package in python that I've installed via pip to construct a graph on a skeleton computed on a set of .tiff 3D images which have the same size (60x60x60) (in reference to https://github.com/yxdragon/sknw) :

```
stack = skimage.io.imread('image1.tiff',plugin='tifffile')
ske = skeletonize_3d(stack).astype(np.uint16)

# build graph from skeleton
graph = sknw.build_sknw(ske)
```

The problem is that the function 'build_sknw(ske)' works for some images and for other I get one of these two errors:

```
IndexError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f133f5f3fe10> in <module>()
----> 1 graph = sknw.build_sknw(ske)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sknw/sknw.pyc in 
build_sknw(ske)
112 def build_sknw(ske):
113     mark(ske)
--> 114     nodes, edges = parse_struc(ske.copy())
115     return build_graph(nodes, edges)
116 

IndexError: index 218852 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 216000
```

or I get a Segmentation fault: 11 error and the ipython is closed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding voxels of value [0][0][0] at the beginning and at the end of the stack (the .tiff 3D image).